# Drawing an out fading transparent oval

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm trying to draw an out fading transparent oval to highlight a tile on a tiled screen. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find an implemented feature in `Swing` that can do that, so I wrote my own:

```
private void drawGradientedOval(Graphics2D g2d, Rectangle bounds) {

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    int loops = (int) Math.min(bounds.getWidth() / 2, bounds.getHeight() / 2);
    int x = bounds.x + (int) (bounds.getWidth() / 2);
    int y = bounds.y + (int) (bounds.getHeight() / 2);
    int scale = 1;
    float alpha = 0.5f;
    float step = alpha / loops;

    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, alpha));
        g2d.drawOval(x--, y--, scale, scale);
        scale += 2;
        alpha -= step;
    }

}
```

The resulting oval looks like(the crop is larger than the oval bounds):

[image]

The result is not a smooth oval, there is a "cross" and some other small artifacts.

I assume this is caused by "overlapping" pixels that are drawn on top of each other.

**Is there an intelligent way of fixing this?**

Please note that I rather avoid implementing a lower level solution like manipulating individual pixels on a `Raster` level simply because the effort involves a huge amount of variables not mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a RadialGradientPaint object to do your painting? Something like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GradOval extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
    private static final float[] FRACTIONS = {0.0f, 1.0f};
    private static final Color[] COLORS = {Color.LIGHT_GRAY, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)};

    public GradOval() {
        setBackground(BG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        float cx = getWidth() / 2f;
        float cy = getHeight() / 2f;
        float radius = cx;       
        Paint paint = new RadialGradientPaint(cy, cy, radius, FRACTIONS, COLORS);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(paint);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());        
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GradOval mainPanel = new GradOval();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GradOval");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This will display as:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the effort, but the solution gradients between colors. Is there a way to use it with transparency? The solution must not override the previous pixel values.

Comment: would setting `COLORS = {new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f), new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0)` work?

Comment: (1+) for the  painting @DimaMaligin -  `would setting....work?` why don't you try I? Only you know the exact requirement.

Comment: @camickr I wasn't asking to test it for me ;), only wanted to save time on false tries. If someone knows it works than I'll implement it.

Comment: @DimaMaligin: I have to agree with Rob on this one. 1) You are the ultimate arbiter as to what fulfills your requirements or not, so it will be up to you to test and determine. 2) It's your question/problem, and we're volunteers, and so the effort of testing should be yours.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Agreed! The solution works. Thak you... Accepted!

Comment: PS: I don't think the question deserved a downvote for that matter. :/

Comment: @DimaMaligin: and I agree with you about the down-vote. Not sure who did this, but only know who didn't. My up-vote should "nullify" the down-vote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Much obliged!